# access mdb date/time issue

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to fetch the record of 3rd june of 2013 from my database which is made in ms access. Dates are stored in the format of dd/MM/yyyy, below is my query

```
AND (a.Date = #" + date + "#) ) order by e.E_ID asc
```

But the amazing thing is i have inserted a record on date of 03/06/2013 which is todays date, while it takes it as 6th march 2013, i have corrected my regional settings, still the same issue. Also in my query i am query for matching date i am using dd/MM/yyyy. Is this a bug from microsoft? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dates are stored in the format of dd/MM/yyyy

I suspect they're not. I suspect they're stored in some native date/time format which is doubtless much more efficient than a 10 character string. (I'm assuming you're using an appropriate field type rather than varchar, for example.) It's important to differentiate between the inherent nature of the data and "how it gets displayed when converted to text".

> But the amazing thing

I don't see this as amazing. I see it as a perfectly natural result of using string conversions unnecessarily. They almost always bite you in the end. You're not trying to represent a string - you're trying to represent a date. So use that type as far as you possibly can.

You should:

- Use parameterized SQL for queries for many reasons - most importantly to avoid SQL injection attacks, but *also* to avoid unneccessary string conversions of this kind
- Specify the parameter value as a `DateTime`, thus avoiding the string conversion

You haven't specified which provider type you're using - my guess is `OleDbConnection` etc. Generally if you look at the documentation for the `Parameters` property of the relevant command class, you'll find an appropriate example. For example, [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) shows a parameterized query on an `OleDbConnection`. One thing worth noting from the docs:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an `OleDbCommand` when `CommandType` is set to `Text`. In this case, the question mark (`?`) placeholder must be used. [...] 
>   Therefore, the order in which `OleDbParameter` objects are added to the `OleDbParameterCollection` must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.